# Creating Checklist, send child values only if checked

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, submit

So if I have 3 and they select 2, how would I make sure I only get the values of the child values that are selected?

```
   <form action="nextpage.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sendme[]"> Do you Want this sent</input>
    <input type="text" name="name"> </input> This is name
     <input type="text" name="email[]"></input> This is your email

    <input type="checkbox" name="sendme[]"> Do you Want this sent</input>
    <input type="text" name="name"> </input> This is name
     <input type="text" name="email[]"></input> This is your email 

    <input type="checkbox" name="sendme[]"> Do you Want this sent</input>
    <input type="text" name="name"> </input> This is name
     <input type="text" name="email[]"></input> This is your email 

    <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: inputs should be in the format `<input type="checkbox" name="sendme[]" value="Do you Want this sent" />` not `<input type="checkbox" name="sendme[]"> Do you Want this sent</input>`

Comment: I mean when I send it, it will send the first value, but it will also add the name and email for ones that aren't selected.

I only want to get values of the ones that the parent checkbox is clicked on.

Comment: That would require JS, are you ok with that?  Otherwise you would just need to do server side processing of the form to use only the elements corresponding to the checked checkboxes.

Comment: how would I do the second in php?

Comment: server side processing that would be